# How to intercept application communication before encryption?

Tags: c++, windows, ssl

I am trying to reverse engineer the protocol a Windows application uses to communicate over the network. It communicates to a server using a TLS encrypted connection.

I would like to intercept the application's relevant calls (to the TLS library, or to the Secure Sockets API), and see its plaintext messages.

Full disclosure: This is not for any enrichment purposes, but to improve an open source project.

I've tried running the application under Wine on Linux where the above would amount to a LD_PRELOAD trick used to intercept calls to send().
https://rafalcieslak.wordpress.com/2013/04/02/dynamic-linker-tricks-using-ld_preload-to-cheat-inject-features-and-investigate-programs/ 
https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/networking/tls.html

That did not work. That is why I am now trying to intercept such calls on Windows.

Comment: No need to intercept the API calls.   If it is an open source project then you can access the source code that produces the data before feeding it to the TLS library or Secure Sockets API.

Comment: Peter, thank you for your comment. The Windows application is closed source. Knowledge of the protocol would help improve a different, open source application.

Comment: Is it strictly necessary to intercept the API calls? I would imagine it would be easier to use any existing TLS MITM proxy to intercept data in flight (if you can get the application to accept your own certificates, e.g. by adding a custom root certificate to the Root CA store)

Comment: @Cybran, it probably is not necessary to intercept system calls. Your idea might work. Thanks for the suggestion!

Answer (score 2):

Adding detail to @Cybran's solution:

1. Install mitmproxy. Run it once, find the CA certificate it generated (`mitmproxy-ca.p12`) and install it as a Root CA in Windows. mitmproxy provides instructions how to do that.
2. Launch `mitmdump -w outfile`. It usually runs on port 8080. Figure out on what interface/ip.
3. In Windows, under Settings->Network Settings, there is an option to manually configure a proxy. Point it to the interface/ip and port where mitmdump is running.
4. Launch Windows application and in the mitmdump terminal observe traffic urls. The outfile will contain the plaintext traffic itself in a nearly human-readable format.

Comment: This only works for pre-known ports.
Would be good to have also an answer, which works for dynamically generated port numbers e.g. by intercepting calls to the APIs as @RoundObject asked for.